Visual Studio 2022 - Automatically Refactoring CS files on file rename, how to disable?
In Visual Studio 2022 (full-fat), whenever I rename a CS file, it refactors the class name automatically when I hit enter. Which is causing problems refactoring across the code base as you often want to choose whether or not to do that refactor.
It used to ask, I'm sure of it, and there was probably a checkbox as to whether to ask again in future that I may have accidently applied.
If so, is there a way to reset this flag, or some setting to force it to ask, or alternatively never refactor on file rename? I can't find it in the options or through search.

Nevermind, I obviously found it the second I posted it, but for anyone else struggling with this:

Under Projects and Solutions > Prompt for symbolic renaming when renaming files.
This explains why a search for "rename" does not show this setting, as you'd have had to have searched for "renaming". Excellent.
